# how to do a transparency gradient on an element in css?

Tags: html, css

Is there any possible way or workaround that I can fade an element from 100% to 0% opacity top to bottom? Similar to a linear gradient background, but transparency on the element itself (not the background color).

[image: The idea is that on the hover state, it would brighten up, and when clicked, move up to the spot of the active popup]

The idea is that on the hover state, it would brighten up, and when clicked, move up to the spot of the active popup

Comment: There are lots of "CSS Gradient Generators" on the web.  You can find one to get the correct colours/transparencies.  After that look at using a toolkit (jQuery for example) to manage the transition process.  HTML5 has good support for gradients and transitions,

Comment: Thanks Chris. I believe you're referring to background-color linear gradients? All the gradient generators I've seen generate css code for a background-color. However I have not found a way to use css to create an opaciity gradient on an element (applying the opacity to the children inside the element etc.) I don't believe there's a built in css property to do this, but I have seen some cool tricks people have come up with here on stack overflow for other css concepts, so i thought i would ask the community

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  A (semi-)transparent CSS background colour does not effect content nor children.  The `opacity` css element will but I don't think you can do gradients with this.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I see two different types of transparency, the first one is a alpha css just like that:

```
    div {
         opacity: 0.5;
         filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    }
```

this style made transparent the entired div (Custom sharing dialogue) and the other css that creates a linear gradient style on the button of the page:

```
#bottom_fade { z-index: 99; 
           position: fixed;     
           bottom: 0%;
           background-image: url("bottom-fade.png"); 
           /*in your case use a grey image with transparency*/
     }
```

or you can use a div that covers all the button of your pages and add a linear-gradient:

```
#grad {
     background: red; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, yellow); 
     /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
     background: -o-linear-gradient(red, yellow); 
     /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(red, yellow); 
     /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
     background: linear-gradient(red, yellow); /* Standard syntax */
}
```

hopefully this snippets helps you, regards.

Answer (score -1):

There are alot of online css generators why don't you use that.

Here is a help link for you, go there and generate your desired Gradient.

**http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/**